# Oncuechange event trigger a fade-in/fade-out animation inside the P tag of html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio, webvtt

I'm fairly new to web development, just started to learn the javascript.. So beside learning I'm trying to build a web page where the lyrics will be shown inside a **p** tag, which is synced with an audio file. The subtitle source is given by vet file extension, and with the help of javascript "cuechange" event I'm trying to inject fat text inside that **p** tag. Till now everything is working fine. But one more thing I wanna add, that is I want to have a fade-in/fadeout effect animation on cue change event listener inside my **p** tag, means for each sentence of the lyrics I want a fade-in/fadeout animation before and after.
 I tried to add css animation directly on p element, but that's not really firing it with an event listener.
Can anyone help me out about this?

The github link is given below: https://github.com/beatzonic/Audio-Lyrics-Subtitle

```js
 document.getElementById('my_audio').textTracks[0].addEventListener('cuechange', function() {
    document.getElementById('lyric').innerText = this.activeCues[0].text;
    
});
```

```css
body{
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#lyrics_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p{
    
    font-size: 2em;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 600;

}



@keyframes fadein{
    
   0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    } 
    
}
```

```html
    <div id="lyrics_container">

        
        <audio id="my_audio" controls>
          <source src="https://github.com/beatzonic/Audio-Lyrics-Subtitle/raw/master/in_case_you_didnt_know.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          <track id="sub" kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beatzonic/Audio-Lyrics-Subtitle/master/in_case_you_didnt_know.txt.vtt" srclang="en" default>
          Your browser does not support the audio tag.
        </audio>
        
        <p id="lyric" class="lyrics-class"></p>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function which adds a class now and removes the class after a given amount of time. Check out this example down here. It adds a `transition` property to a given element and adds the `is-animating` class to it. Then after half of the `duration` has passed it will change the `content` and remove the `is-animating` class again. Then after the animations have been completed, remove the `transition` property as well.

This function will return another function to make use of a *closure*. This ensures that when you try to animate the text **before** the previous animation is finished it will first cancel the previous animation before starting the new one. Otherwise you would get overlapping transitions.

```
function buildAnimator(element, duration) {
    let timeouts = [];

    return function(content) {
        if (timeouts.length > 0) {
          for (const timeout of timeouts) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
          }

          timeouts.length = 0;
        }

        const halfDuration = duration / 2;
        element.style.transition = `opacity ${halfDuration}ms ease-in-out`;
        element.classList.add('is-animating');

        const firstTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            element.textContent = content;
            element.classList.remove('is-animating');
        }, halfDuration);

        const secondTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            element.style.transition = '';
            currentTimeout = null;
        }, duration);

        timeouts.push(firstTimeout, secondTimeout);
    }
}
```

Now build your `animateLyrics` function by calling the `buildAnimator` function above with the element that you want to animate and the duration of the total animation, so that is fade in and fade out combined.

Then add it in your `cuechange` event handler. Pass the newly updated text of the cue to the `animateLyrics` function to change the `textContent` property of the element you want to animate.

```
const textTrack = document.getElementById('sub');
const lyric = document.getElementById('lyric');
const animateLyrics = buildAnimator(lyric, 500);

textTrack.addEventListener('cuechange', function(event) {
    animateLyrics(event.target.activeCues[0].text);
});
```

And in CSS, tell the browser what it should transition to when the class is added. For example:

```
#lyric.is-animating {
    opacity: 0;
}
```